# Minimum Permissions in order to perform Merge

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, merge

I have implemented a custom solution for Account Edit where i have overriden Account edit action with a custom Lightning Component. I have some criteria where when they are true, i call via Apex, Merge Operation for some Accounts. This functionality works perfectly for System Administrator. However, i see strange behavior when i try to do the same with a low permissions user. Merge operation does not seem to be performed, so my question is very specific, cause i am new to Salesforce and maybe i do something wrong: What are the minimum permissions needed for a user in order to perform Merge Operation?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be a tricky operation. Here's the [official documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=account_merge_classic.htm&type=5), and it applies to both Classic and Lightning:

> Delete on business or person accounts
>
> AND
>
> Edit on related objects, such as opportunities and cases
>
> AND
>
> You must be a Salesforce admin, the account owner, or a user above the account > owner in the role hierarchy

Does your low-perm User meet all of these criteria at present?

Comment: Thank you, Dan!